# Time complexity

Tags: java, time, complexity-theory

I am trying to find the time complexity of these procedures but I am not sure if they are good.

I think this is O(n)

```
static void P1(int n ){
   for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
      Procedure();
}
```

I think this is O(n^2)

```
static void P2(int n) {
   for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) 
    for(int j=1; j<=n; j++)
      Procedure();
}
```

O(n)+O(n)

```
static void P3(int n) {
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     Procedure();
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     Procedure();
}
```

100+n+100?

```
static void P4(int n) {
   for ( int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
     for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
       for (int k = 1; k <= 100; k++)
         Procedure();
}
```

O(n*i)?

```
static void P5(int n) {
   for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
       Procedure();
}
```

?

```
static void P6(int n) {
   for (int i = 1; i <= n/2; i++)
     for ( int j = 1; j <= n/4; j++)
       for (int k = 1; k <= n/8; k++)
         Procedure();
}
```

Comment: `100+n+100?` just O(N), constants are skipped, `O(n*i)?` O(N^2) because second loop ultimately depends on N too `?` O(N^3) because constants are ignored

Comment: Looks a lot like a homework exercise (you should tag the question if that's the case.) Can you elaborate on *why* you think the function have the given complexity ? Can you go back to the definition of the O() notation to justify your choices ?

Comment: This assumes a lot about `Procedure()` also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Procedure() is O(1), then :

I think this is O(n) **correct**

```
static void P1(int n ){
   for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
      Procedure();
}
```

I think this is O(n^2) **correct**

```
static void P2(int n) {
   for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) 
    for(int j=1; j<=n; j++)
      Procedure();
}
```

O(n)+O(n) **correct, but O(n+n)=O(2n)=O(n)**

```
static void P3(int n) {
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     Procedure();
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     Procedure();
}
```

100+n+100? **false, it is multiplicated : O(100*n*100)=O(n)**

```
static void P4(int n) {
   for ( int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
     for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
       for (int k = 1; k <= 100; k++)
         Procedure();
}
```

O(n*i)? **You cant use i** it does not have exact value. If you look how much times inner loop is executed, it is `1+2+3+4+...+n-3+n-2+n-1`, which is `n*(n-1)/2`, you can multiply it : `n*(n-1)/2=n^2/2-n/2` which is assymptotically `n^2/2-n/2=Theta(n^2)`

**The result is O(n^2)**

```
static void P5(int n) {
   for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
       Procedure();
}
```

n/2 * n/4 * n/8 = n^3/64 = **O(n^3)**

```
static void P6(int n) {
   for (int i = 1; i <= n/2; i++)
     for ( int j = 1; j <= n/4; j++)
       for (int k = 1; k <= n/8; k++)
         Procedure();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity of

```
static void P3(int n){
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     Procedure();
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     Procedure();
}
```

can be written as a function of O(2n) as we need to eliminate constants it becomes O(n)

Time Complexity of

```
static void P4(int n) {
   for ( int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
     for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
       for (int k = 1; k <= 100; k++)
         Procedure();
}
```

100+n+100 => O(n*100*100) => O(n)

Time complexity of

```
static void P6(int n) {
   for (int i = 1; i <= n/2; i++)
     for ( int j = 1; j <= n/4; j++)
       for (int k = 1; k <= n/8; k++)
         Procedure();
}
```

is O(n^3)

Remember that we are not calculating the no.of instructions computer executes using time complexity. The Big-O just tells how our execution time varies with increase or decrease in input.

consider reading [Time Complexity](http://www.studytonight.com/data-structures/time-complexity-of-algorithms)